# How to Compile Ghostscript for ImageMagick on Android?

Tags: android, android-ndk, imagemagick, ghostscript, mupdf

I've been googling for hours but to no avail.
I have successfully compiled ImageMagick on Android via the NDK, but cannot use it to open pdf files because this requires Ghostscript.
A lot of ghostscript for android searches has led me to believe ghostscript's android port is MuPdf. Will compiling MuPDF's NDK source as a dependency for ImageMagick work for me?

Comment: I made it work by cross compiling it for android. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37478507/cross-compiling-ghostscript-for-android-what-host-should-i-use

Answer (score 2):

There is no port of Ghostscript for Android, we've never done one and I'm not aware of one. MuPDF is a totally different product.

So no, you can't compile MuPDF for Android and expect it to work in place of Ghostscript for ImageMagick.

It should be possible to port GS over to Android, and we would be interested in hearing if you manage that.