# Cross Compiling ghostscript for android, what host should I use?

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, ghostscript

Hi Guys I am using [this](http://blog.jimjh.com/compiling-open-source-libraries-with-android-ndk-part-2.html) tutorial to build ghostscript-9.19 to be able to use in my android application to convert eps document to pdf. It fails while configure. Here are the logs

```
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles...
no
checking for gcc... arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -- 
sysroot=/<path>/android-ndk-   
r11c/platforms/android-17/arch-arm/
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... configure: error: in    
`/<path>/ghostscript-9.19/tiff-config':
configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
See `config.log' for more details
configure: error: libtiff configure script failed
```

This is the build file I am running

```
#!/bin/sh
# Compiles ghostscript for Android
# Make sure you have NDK_ROOT defined in .bashrc or .bash_profile

INSTALL_DIR="`pwd`/app/jni/gs"
SRC_DIR="`pwd`/../ghostscript-9.19"

cd $SRC_DIR

export
PATH="/<path>/android-ndk-r11c/toolchains/arm-        
linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin:$PATH"
export SYS_ROOT="/<path>/Android/android-ndk-
r11c/platforms/android-17/arch-arm/"
export CC="arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=$SYS_ROOT"
export LD="arm-linux-androideabi-ld"
export AR="arm-linux-androideabi-ar"
export RANLIB="arm-linux-androideabi-ranlib"
export STRIP="arm-linux-androideabi-strip"

mkdir -p $INSTALL_DIR
./configure --host=arm-linux-androideabi --build=x86_64-apple-darwin
--prefix=$INSTALL_DIR LIBS="-lc -lgcc"

make PREFIX=$INSTALL_DIR
make install DESTDIR=$INSTALL_DIR

exit 0
```

I am using --host=arm-linux-androideabi. What host should i use? What do I need to change in ghostScript project to make compile in successfully?
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Were you eventually able to fix your problems with ghostscript and android? The PIE problem seems a matter of adding -fPIC to compilation flags.

Comment: yes, I was able to solve the problem. I compiled the commit mentioned in the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cross compiling Ghostscript is pretty involved, partly because the Ghostscript build relies on building and running interim tools (genarch, genconf, mkromfs and echogs) which, obviously, must be built with the native compiler, rather than the cross compiler.

I think the problem you are seeing is because the call to the libtiff configure doesn't pass on the required options.

You may be better served grabbing, and tweaking the two files (a makefile and a header) from this commit:
[Makefile for Android MuPDF libgs.so](http://git.ghostscript.com/?p=user/robin/ghostpdl.git;a=commit;h=e350758ceb8d9f7ec6bb209908a6ce1fe35e2397)

and tweaking it to match your requirements.

There is a basic guide of what to do for cross compiling at the bottom of this page:
[Ghostscript FAQ](http://ghostscript.com/FAQ.html)

I have a "project" to improve support for cross compiling, but it is slow going at the moment.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. It works like a charm and I am able to use ghostscript in my android app.

Comment: Any chance you can share your completed GhostScript lib?

Comment: @chrisl I am in trouble again. The gs binary i got from above is not working on Android 6.0.1 giving error "only position independent executables (PIE) are supported.". Since i just used the make file i can not make gs PIE. I have looked a lot to fix it but did not work. I even tries bypass-pie.zip on my phone. No luck. Is there any help you can provide?

Comment: @chrisl, do you have plans to move to a more modern build tool? I did esplorative attempt to create CMakeLists.txt for ghostscript: genarch can be converted with try_run(), gconfig_h can be implemented with configure(), mkromfs can be implemented with try_compile() and subsequent executions. I stopped on the generation steps needed for genconf, which I didn't quite understand, for the fear to not produce working binary. After this attempt I estimated a 2 full-time week task (for me) to produce something useful, but it seems perfectly doable and it would greatly simplify the build system.

Comment: No, we're definitely never going to try to move to CMake.